# How do I get today's date in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandasql

I am trying to use Pandasql to query my dataframe. However, it is giving me an empty dataframe even though I know it shouldn't. I think it is because I have used today's date incorrectly in the where clause. Below is part of my code:

```
df_event2import=[]
today = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")      
q = """ select e.Date, e.SITA, e.Events from df_event e where e.Date >= date('today') """        
df_event2import=((pandasql.sqldf(q, locals())))
df_all_event2import=df_all_event2import.append(df_event2import,ignore_index=True)
print(df_all_event2import)
```

As requested here is some example data. This is what I get after I use date('now') instead of date('today') in the where clause. As you can see it gives me data from January onward which is not what I want, I want data from today onward.

```
     Date   SITA                      Events
0    2018/01/01  ABZPD  New Years Day Bank Holiday
1    2018/01/02  ABZPD                            
2    2018/01/03  ABZPD                            
3    2018/01/04  ABZPD                            
4    2018/01/05  ABZPD                            
5    2018/01/06  ABZPD                            
6    2018/01/07  ABZPD                            
7    2018/01/08  ABZPD                            
8    2018/01/09  ABZPD                            
9    2018/01/10  ABZPD                            
10   2018/01/11  ABZPD                            
11   2018/01/12  ABZPD                            
12   2018/01/13  ABZPD                            
13   2018/01/14  ABZPD                            
14   2018/01/15  ABZPD                            
15   2018/01/16  ABZPD                            
16   2018/01/17  ABZPD                            
17   2018/01/18  ABZPD                            
18   2018/01/19  ABZPD
```

Comment: `'now'` not `'today'`

Comment: @AlexK. That doesn't give me an empty dataframe which is a step forward but it still doesn't give me what I want. It gives me all the entries from 2018-01-01 onward instead of today onward

Comment: @Sorath What's in `e.Date`? Are you sure it's a valid date?

Comment: @Sorath Nope, not a valid date.

Comment: @Schwern Could that be where my issue lies then? How do I turn it into a valid date so that it is comparable with date('now')?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@user2993886's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49737230/14660), `2018/01/19` is not a valid date in SQLite. [The formats are documented](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), see "Time Strings".

You can convert `2018/01/19` to `2018-01-19` with `replace(e.Date, '/', '-')`. It would probably be best to do this permanently with an `update` and to use the right format when inserting. Using the native date format will be faster (queries can be indexed) and avoids this sort of bug in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. I am trying to update my dataframe using "  k = """ update df_event set Date = REPLACE(Date, '/', '-') """
        ((pandasql.sqldf(k, locals())))"    "  but it says 'no such table: df_event' when there clearly is because it does execute for the query q.

Comment: @Sorath Could be any number of things, and I don't know how pandas works. You'll have to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `date('today')` you should use `date('now')`

More details in the SQLite documentation:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: `conn.execute("SELECT date();").fetchone()` or just leave it empty ;P

Comment: I used date('now') and that just gives me everything from 2018-01-01 onward, when in fact i only need today onward.

Comment: What is your system date? When I use `select date('now');` i get today's date `2018-04-09`

Comment: Same with me. When I type in "
import pandasql
today = ((pandasql.sqldf("""select date('now')""" , locals())))
print(today)" I get today's date

Comment: Can you post some example data?

Comment: but also, if `date('now')` gets you today's date, then that answers your original question

Comment: I have posted some example data. It does answer my question of how to get today's date but it doesn't give me data from today's date onward